# Laravel Installation directory location

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel's documentation does not explicitly say where to execute "laravel new project_name"? Should it be executed at the webserver's root that is htdocs or www? I use WAMP server in Windows.

Comment: 2 correct answers, will just check the first one no way to check both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be executed at the parent folder of `htdocs` or `www`.

The laravel folder can't live in `htdocs`, as it will expose all sensitive files.

After that, you must map `laravel_myapp/public` to something as `htdocs/myapp`.

You can also `symlink` the `laravel_myapp/public` folder to where you want in `htdocs`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, but I would put it in htcdocs/www because is the default folder configured in apache by WAMP, anyway you can change the [documentroot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#documentroot) of your server if you want.

As long as you have the right folder permissions and the project is created under your root folder laravel shouldn't have any problem with that.

Hope this helps you :)